# Differences on Windows Dll exported functions using VS 2022 vs CLion and Cmake

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, cmake, jetbrains-ide

I need to build a C++ library that I'm currently working on for OSX, Windows and Linux. Previously I have built my library on Visual Studio 2022 as a C++ project, then after some research, I moved to CLion and CMake to handle the different builds for each OS that I needed to, but found the following differences when building the Windows DLL on VS 2022 and CLion.

My library is called "Connect". After building it using VS 2022 and running `dumpbin Connect.dll /EXPORTS` I got the following:

```
Dump of file .\Connect.dll

File Type: DLL

  Section contains the following exports for Connect.dll

    00000000 characteristics
    FFFFFFFF time date stamp
        0.00 version
           1 ordinal base
           5 number of functions
           5 number of names

    ordinal hint RVA      name

          1    0 0001167C CreateConnect = @ILT+1655(_CreateConnect)
          2    1 000114BA LaunchScm = @ILT+1205(_LaunchScm)
          3    2 00011320 PrintJvmVersion = @ILT+795(_PrintJvmVersion)
          4    3 00011659 StartJvm = @ILT+1620(_StartJvm)
          5    4 0001166D StopJvm = @ILT+1640(_StopJvm)

  Summary

        1000 .00cfg
        1000 .data
        2000 .idata
        1000 .msvcjmc
        3000 .rdata
        1000 .reloc
        1000 .rsrc
        F000 .text
       10000 .textbss
```

But when I build the same source code using CLion and cmake using autodetected VS 2022 compiler toolchain I got the following:

```
Dump of file .\Connect.dll

File Type: DLL

  Section contains the following exports for Connect.dll

    00000000 characteristics
    FFFFFFFF time date stamp
        0.00 version
           1 ordinal base
           5 number of functions
           5 number of names

    ordinal hint RVA      name

          1    0 00001C30 CreateConnect
          2    1 00001C60 LaunchScm
          3    2 00001CC0 PrintJvmVersion
          4    3 00001D30 StartJvm
          5    4 00001D50 StopJvm

  Summary

        1000 .data
        2000 .rdata
        1000 .reloc
        1000 .rsrc
        3000 .text
```

Can you explain me what this difference means? Am I missing something on CMake? the DLL built from CLion is giving me issues because I'm including the DLL on a C# project and I'm getting an `EntrypointNotFoundException` when looking for any of those exported functions, but the DLL built from VS 2022 works great.

Here is the Source Code of my Connect.h where I'm using `__declspec(dllexport)` to export the functions I need.

```
#if defined _WIN64 || _WIN32
class __declspec(dllexport) Connect
{
public:
    void StartJvm(const char* javaHome, const char* classPath);
    void StopJvm();
    void PrintJvmVersion();
    bool LaunchScm(const char* host, const char* proxyHost, int proxyPort, const char** properties, int propLength);
    bool StopScm();
    SdcConnectionManager GetConnectionManager() { return connectionManager; }

private:
    JavaVM* jvm; // Pointer to the JVM (Java Virtual Machine)
    static bool threadProc(void* args);
    SdcConnectionManager connectionManager;
    void* GetStartJvmFunc(std::string);
    HMODULE DllHandler;
};
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) Connect * CreateConnect() { return new Connect(); }
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void StartJvm(Connect * connect, const char* javaHome, const char* classPath) { connect->StartJvm(javaHome, classPath); }
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void StopJvm(Connect * connect) { connect->StopJvm(); }
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void PrintJvmVersion(Connect * connect) { connect->PrintJvmVersion(); }
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) bool LaunchScm(Connect * connect, const char* host, const char* proxyHost, int proxyPort, const char** properties, int propLength)
{
    return connect->LaunchScm(host, proxyHost, proxyPort, properties, propLength);
}
```

Here is my `CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
project(Connect)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

# Include JNI
find_package(JNI REQUIRED)
include_directories(${JNI_INCLUDE_DIRS})

# Build Connect Dll and copy to /lib
add_library(Connect SHARED Connect.cpp ConnectionManager.cpp)
```

I'm using Windows 10, Visual Studio 22 and CLion 21

Comment: did you set a calling convention? Because C# by default will look for `__stdcall` and not `__cdecl`